# CSS and positioning a group of divs

Tags: html, css

I would like to get this kind of group of X letters.

```
          X
     X
X         X
     X
X         X
     X
          X
```

Here is my HTML/CSS code which does not do what I want.

```
<div>
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle">
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
<div style="clear:both;margin-top:50%;margin-bottom:50%">X</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What is the problem? Thanks for any help!

Comment: margin:1em; should be enough to start with  https://jsfiddle.net/e086qn3c/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex and margin can help too, just with a basis of 2 rules/lines.
Example with a list :

```css
/* basis */

/* parent */

ul {
  display: flex;
}
/* children */

li {
  margin: auto 1em;
}
/*reset li ================ */

li {
  display: block;
  /* reset list-item */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

for older browser , table-layout will do too (2rules, 3lines)

```css
ul {
  display: table;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

finaly inline-block also 3lines, 2rules

```css
ul {
  display: block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
    <p>X</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`<ul>`, `<li>`, `<p>` , can be any tag with or without `id`,`class` if structure is respected.

Answer (score 2):

Just add some margin for the spacing: https://jsfiddle.net/e086qn3c/

CSS:

```
div div:first-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap everything in a container, then use flex on both the container as well as the individual divs containing the X's. [Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/rhwwb5cr/3/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  width: 10rem;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.parent div {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div>X</div>
    <div>X</div>
    <div>X</div>
    <div>X</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>
  <div>X</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```